# Problems with query using timespan

Tags: postgresql, ormlite-servicestack

I am doing a manual query to my postgresql database (using `OrmLiteReadConnectionExtensions.SqlList<T>`) that has a `TimeSpan` argument.

SericeStack.Ormlite is converting `TimeSpan` to `::time` instead of `::interval` as I would expect it.

More specifically: `TimeSpan.FromDays(3)` is converted to `((E'00:00:00.000000')::time)`(taken form pg logs).

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

My current work-around is to use the C# `string.Format` for this problematic parameter instead of the safe and recommended™ `@paramname` supported by `SqlList<T>`.

This could be considered dangerous, but since the parameter is a double, I'm probably Okay.

The relevant part of the string is:

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "RESTOFTHEQUERY ('{0:0.####} seconds'::interval) RESTOFTHEQUERY", timespan.TotalSeconds);
```

Don't forget to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you can just cast a `time` value to `interval`. Demo

```
SELECT now()::time::interval
```

So append `::interval` in your manual query and you should be fine - except for intervals > 24 hours of course.

Comment: You miss the point, that Ormlite is truncating values when writing the query as `::time`. `((E'00:00:00.000000')::time)::interval` is indeed an interval and not a time, but still does not represent the 3 days from `TimeSpan.FromDays(3)`.

Comment: @ANeves is right. If it weren't for > 24 hours time would probably work just as good without converting. (Actually not because there seems to also be another problem with very small TimeSpan values in OrmLite, but that's another story).